# Making an AJAX call to check uniqueness before doing a save

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a ASP button on which i have to submit the form and save the details to DB. Now before saving i want to make an ajax call to the DB, checking for the uniqueness of a particular parameter on the form. so to achieve this i wrote a jquery function onClientClick of the button something like:

```
AjaxGet1(serviceURL, null, function (response) {
        alert("inside success");
       }, onAjaxError);

function AjaxGet1(serviceUrl, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
var postData = data;
if (errorCallback == undefined) {
    errorCallback = onAjaxError;
}
$.ajax({
    cache: true,
    type: "GET",
    async : false,
    url: serviceUrl, //+ "/" + method,
    contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
    data: postData,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: successCallback,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: errorCallback
});
```

}

This call hits the service which returns a true/false. I am not able to see any response.

Can anybody provide any directions ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What's your console saying?

Answer (score 0):

What does your successCallback() do?

Try this and you should get an answer:

```
AjaxGet1(serviceURL, null, function (response) {
        alert("inside success");
       }, onAjaxError);

function AjaxGet1(serviceUrl, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
var postData = data;
if (errorCallback == undefined) {
    errorCallback = onAjaxError;
}
$.ajax({
    cache: true,
    type: "GET",
    async : false,
    url: serviceUrl, //+ "/" + method,
    contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
    data: postData,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: errorCallback
});
```

Comment: Even when i change my code, to what you suggested I get the same problem. Adding on to the information i m trying to debug this in firebug and there when i check for the value of response. It says " response is undefined".

Also when i hit the same service url in browser directly i get a proper repsonse.